# Saving streamed Data from Unity in a csv File

Tags: c#, database, csv, unity-game-engine

I have to record the coordinate-data (vector of x,y,z) of an eye-tracking System and save it, for later evaluation. The whole eye-tracking System is integrated inside a Head-mounted-Display and the software runs over Unity.

After some research, I figured out that saving the Data in a CSV file would probably the easiest way. This is what I got so far:

```
void update()
    {

    string filePath = @"C:\Data.csv";
    string delimiter = ",";

    Vector3 leftGazeDirection = smiInstance.smi_GetLeftGazeDirection();
    Vector3 rightGazeDirection = smiInstance.smi_GetRightGazeDirection();


    float[][] output = new float[][]{
    new float[]{leftGazeDirection.x},
    new float[]{leftGazeDirection.y},
    new float[]{leftGazeDirection.z},
    new float[]{rightGazeDirection.x},
    new float[]{rightGazeDirection.y},
    new float[]{rightGazeDirection.z} };


    int length = output.GetLength(0);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));

    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Data.csv", sb.ToString());
}
```

What this gives me out is a CSV file with the Vector of the latest Position of the Gazedirection. What I need would be a Record of all the Gazedirections that were made in one Session. Is it possible to get something like this?

Can I somehow modify my Code to achieve this or should I try something completely different?
Since I'm very newbie to unity and programming in general I just have a lack of vocabulary and don't know what to search for to solve my problem..

I would be very thankful if somebody could help me. :)

Comment: Any reason why you just use new float[] for storing a simple float value? And saving it as a multidimensional array? I believe you don't need to save it as multidimensional array as its just 6 float values for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. A good question, and well set out.

Presumably after you save this data away, you want to do something with it. I would suggest that your life is going to be a lot easier if you were to create a database to store your data. There are tons of tutorials on this sort of thing, and since you are already writing in C# it should not be too hard for you.

I would be creating a SQL Server database - either the Express version or Developer Version, both would be free for you.

I would steer away from trying Entity Framework or similar at this stage, I would just use the basic SQLClient to connect and write to your database.

Once you start using this then adding something like a Session column to separate one session from the next becomes easy, and all sorts of analysis you might want to do onthe data will also become much easier.

Hope this helps, and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have data for one entire session. Look no further than **File.AppendAllText**. In this scenario I'm assuming that you have 6 values for two gaze pointers. In that case you don't need to write it down as multidimensional array as it is just wasting allocated memory.

Here we can proceed to save it as 6 values for each iteration of your loop.

```
string filePath = @"C:\Data.csv";
string delimiter = ",";

void Start()
{
  if(File.Exists(filePath))
      File.Delete(filePath);
}

void Update
{
    Vector3 leftGazeDirection = smiInstance.smi_GetLeftGazeDirection();
    Vector3 rightGazeDirection = smiInstance.smi_GetRightGazeDirection();

    float[] output = new float[]{
    leftGazeDirection.x,
    leftGazeDirection.y,
    leftGazeDirection.z,
    rightGazeDirection.x,
    rightGazeDirection.y,
    rightGazeDirection.z };

    int length = output.Length;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
         sb.AppendLine(output[index],delimiter));

    if(!File.Exists(filePath))
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
    else
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
}
```

AppendAllText will keep on appending file till the end of execution. Note that this solution has downside that is at the start we will delete the file for each session so you will need to manually keep track of each session.

So if you want to keep a bunch of files related to each session and not to overrride the same file we can include the date and time stamp while creating each file. So instead of deleting old file for each new session we are creating file for each session and writing in it. Only start method will need to change to handle datetime stamp for file name appending. Rest of the Update loop will be same.

```
string filePath = @"C:\Data";
string delimiter = ",";

void Start()
{
    filePath = filePath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss") + ".csv";
}
```

Comment: Hey, 
thank you for your quick response. The time stamp worked perfectly! I tried it with AppendAllText but I still only get the latest and not the whole Data.. I have now the exact same Code like you with the only difference that I'm calling my update function in the start function.. might that be the problem?

Comment: Yes that's because start function runs only once while update is called till the end of execution. And you should not move the contents in the Update loop. As Update function runs once per frame. Else if you are not comfortable using it in update then Start a `coroutine` and make it run repeatedly. Also you can use `invokerepeatedly` incase you want a lazy way out of writing coroutine.

Comment: Yep, that was my Problem. It works now! Thank you very much for your help! 
I've got one last Question. Is it somehow possible to give the csv file a more table like look for a better overview?Maybe by declaring the names of the columns with "X""Y""Z" before writing in them?

Comment: You will need to ask it as another question. The above solution is the question you have asked.